# Auto resize Vim focused window when open it the first time

Tags: vim-windows, microsoft-windows

I'm using [vim-autoresize](https://github.com/kovetskiy/vim-autoresize) for resize windows. It uses:

```
augroup _vim-autoresize
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter * call autoresize#resize()
augroup end
```

But `WinEnter` just changes behavior when your cursor in another window and jump back

[image]

How autoresize when open the window?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the effect only on opening new window, then try `WinNew` or `BufWinEnter` as `WinEnter` triggers every time you enter a window.

You can add another `autocmd` for the cases when you want to call the function:

```
augroup _vim-autoresize
    autocmd!
    " Resize a newly opened one
    autocmd BufWinEnter * call autoresize#resize()
    " Resize upon switching window
    autocmd WinEnter    * call autoresize#resize()
augroup end
```

Comment: I want apply both when open new window and after jump to other window. How to do that?

Comment: you can add another `autocmd`, as in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the answer with your code, change `BufWinEnter` to `BufNew`, but it just work with normal buffer, not `help file` buffer

Comment: it seems to me that this [if block](https://github.com/kovetskiy/vim-autoresize/blob/4747e44ef5a41c6773fe079ac7f62b9523889627/autoload/autoresize.vim#L2) was executed. Can you `:echo g:autoresize_disabled_filetypes`? We may need to know what it contains.

Comment: I just set ['nerdtree'] for this variable

Comment: I will to test the plugin later and see if I can give you an answer.

Comment: @PhamHung I cannot reproduce your error. The plugin works correctly on help as other file types.

Comment: Can you share you gif or video in here for me(with help file)

Comment: well, here is your [video](https://youtu.be/KSbE4RPG6WY)

Comment: check my comment on Youtube

Comment: Please debug the package by yourself, check which part is not working and try fixing it. If you find a bug you can't fix by yourself, post the question here then we can help. You can also open an issue on the github of the plugin.